# Can i use my android phone as an emulator for Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

i want use my android phone as an emulator for Xamarin apps , can i use it with ADB to build apps ?

because i was using it on react-native as an Emulator !

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debugging/debug-on-device/

Comment: Why would you use it as an emulator? Why wouldn't you just run directly on it?

Comment: because my emulator works very slow :/